# How to insert data from another file's particular lines

Tags: insert-mode, ex-mode

I want to insert data from another file , especially particular lines[10-23] from the file. I tried the following

```
:r filename 10-23
```

But It returns the following error

> E172: Only one file name allowed

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
:r! sed -n 10,23p filename
```